# Historical Crypto Data

Tags: api, currencies

I'm looking for for historical data on crypto currencies that tracks down to at least the hour if not 5 minutes for each day for at least the past year. I need OHLV price, and volume at a minimum for each interval, but further trade data would be a great plus. I would prefer to get this from an API if one is available, but at least some csv's would help to start with, all the historical sources i see only track on a once per day basis.

Comment: maybe dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143266

Answer (score 1):

Free version to the previously proposed paid version:

> Actually, you CAN get the whole Bitcoin trades history from Bitcoincharts in CSV format here : http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/
>
> it is updated twice a day for active exchanges, and there is a few dead exchanges, too.
>
> EDIT: Since there are no column headers in the CSVs, here's what they are : column 1) the trade's timestamp, column 2) the price, column 3) the volume of the trade

Please search first.

Answer (score 0):

[ClueDex](https://www.cluedex.com/api) Offers the online data you need. For OHLCV data, all markets are returned in a single query. You can specify the number of periods you wish, as well as the period interval. Additionally, you can create your own period interval, such as 25-seconds, 47-seconds, or whatever, in addition to the standard period intervals, 1M, 5M, 30M, etc. Cluedex doesn't cache the data either, and they don't impose a delay; you get the data as they receive it. It is a premium service, however.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [historicalcryptodata.com](https://historicalcryptodata.com). Used it before, their pricing is quite cheap and good.